# How do you get a texture to appear on a plane in ARcore?

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

I have been working with the Arcore demo code provided by Google and was working in Android Studio, I would like to avoid using Unity if I can to complete this task.

By default the plane is shown as triangles that are white and the negative space is transparent. I would like to change that plan to rather be a texture that can be tiled throughout the environment, an example of this would be a grass texture.

The default image the plane uses is a file called *trigrid.png* and that is defined in the HelloArActivity.java.

https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/java_arcore_hello_ar/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/helloar/HelloArActivity.java

I tried to replace that with an image file that was just grass texture and called it *floor.png* . This just appears all white and doesn't display the grass at all.

```
        }
    try {
        mPlaneRenderer.createOnGlThread(/*context=*/this, "floor.png");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read plane texture");
    }
```

I have tried adding

```
            GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
```

in the drawPlanes function but that didn't seem to help. I also commented out some of the changing of the colors in drawPlanes as well.

```
        //GLES20.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    //GLES20.glColorMask(false, false, false, true);
    //GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //GLES20.glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
```

I'm not sure what is required to make the texture show. It could have to do with the plane_fragment.shader files but I don't have any experience with those.

Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The shaders are very important. If you want to do any graphics programming in OpenGL, you need to know at least a little bit about shaders.  They are programs that run on the graphics processing unit (GPU) to determine the color of every pixel for every frame.  I quick intro to shaders is here: https://youtu.be/AyNZG_mqGVE.

To answer your question, you can use a new fragment shader which just draws your texture and does not mix in other colors.  This is a quick and dirty solution, in the long term you definitely want to clean up the code to not reference all *uniform* variables that are no longer used.

Specifically:

1. Create a new file called `plane_simple_fragment.shader` in the `src/main/assets/raw` directory.
2. Open it in the editor and add the following code:

   ```
   uniform sampler2D u_Texture;
   varying vec3 v_TexCoordAlpha;

   void main() {
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordAlpha.xy);
   }
   ```
3. Then in `PlaneRenderer` change to the new shader by replacing `R.raw.plane_fragment` with `R.raw.plane_simple_fragment`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for taking the time to help me with this. This new shader made the textures appear.

Comment: Thanks! Now, what do I need to change in the PlaneRenderer 1) to see just one occurence of this texture 2) define its size 3) define its position on the plane ? Thanks !